# Change Sustainsys.Saml2 HttpModule Configuration Programmatically

Tags: saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I have a legacy Web Forms ASP.Net project where I just successfully integrated [Sustainsys.Saml2](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/index.html).

I was wondering how can Make configuration changes programmatically.

For example: in the webconfig, I define my (the SP) metadata url. However, because I run on my Dev machine, plus a test server, a QA server and then production server, each have their own Urls. I want to be able to programmatically change the Url based on the site that is running.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can access the `Options.FromConfiguration` static property and modify it from code. In fact, many of the recent added features are not available in web.config.

The `Options.FromConfiguration` will read settings from web.config on first access, but then the copy in memory is free to modify.